# When orbitals are labeled based on their irreps in D2h, how are the orbitals ordered for an N atom?

Tags: ab-initio-calculations, symmetry, orbitals, cfour

I am performing calculations on a Nitrogen atom using CFOUR. A nitrogen atom has a point group of Dinfh, but ⁠CFOUR uses a lower symmetry of D2h instead. So, looking at the available Irreducible representations for D2h, we see that there are 8 Irreps, and the occupations for each of those Irreps are set in the input file as `OCCUPATION=2-1-1-0-1-0-0-0/2-0-0-0-0-0-0-0` because we are using an unrestricted initial guess.

From the CFOUR manual, I understood that these numbers specify the number of occupied orbitals of each symmetry type. Now, looking at the irreducible representations for D2h, we see that there are 8 irreps and the ordering of the atomic orbitals must be Ag, B3u, B2u and B1u for the first four orbitals.

For the remaining ones I would guess that the ordering is B3g, B2g, B1g, Ag (since they must be the d-type orbitals). However, I am not sure if my reasoning is correct. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Before asking this, I have referred to [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/91346/27342) from Chem.SE, and there is a table there that I found helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "Nitrogen atom has a point group of Dinfh, but ⁠CFOUR uses a lower symmetry of D2h instead"

The point group of the N atom (or any atom) is $K_h$, not $D_{\infty_h}$, the latter would be correct for homonuclear diatomic molecules. When we say "the point group", we usually mean "the point group with the largest number of elements" (this is explained in more words in [this manuscript (PDF)](https://github.com/HPQC-LABS/ZMC/blob/main/PossibleGroupsForMolecules.pdf) of mine).

> "Now looking at the Irreducible representations for D2h, we see that there are 8 Irreps"

This is correct, based on the table that you mentioned. There is a row for each irrep and there's 8 rows in the table.

> "and the ordering of the atomic orbitals must be Ag, B3u, B2u and B1u for the first four orbitals."

I'm not sure if everyone would agree that they "must" be in that order, but s-orbitals are usually associated with $A_g$ in $D_{2h}$, and we can see in the above-mentioned table in the "linear functions, rotations" column, that $B_{3u}$, $B_{2u}$ and $B_{1u}$ correspond to $x$, $y$ and $z$ respectively, so we can associate these with the $p_x$, $p_y$ and $p_z$ orbitals respectively. Since grade 11 (in the Ontario curriculum at least), we do consider the $s$,$p_x$,$p_y$, and $p_z$ orbitals to be the first four. However, again with high-school-level logic, the $2s$ orbital would come before any $p_x$ orbital, so the first four orbitals might be labeled in the following way: $A_g$, $A_g$, and any two of $B_{3u}$, $B_{2u}$ and $B_{1u}$.

> "For the remaining ones I would guess that the ordering is B3g, B2g, B1g, Ag (since they must be the d-type orbitals). However, I am not sure if my reasoning is correct."

If you want to order the orbitals from lowest to highest energy, I think it would be helpful for you to ask a separate question in which you provide an output file (which contains the input file) so that we can see your basis set and the orbital energies. Based on the high-school-level logic in my previous paragraph here, one might even say that $A_g$ would appear again before $B_{3g}$ because the $3s$ orbital comes before any of the $d$-orbitals, but if you have a tiny basis set, maybe you don't even have a 3s orbital available in it (and technically you can make a basis set which has d-orbitals but no p-orbitals)!